# Merge org-mode headings without breaking links

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I have a large collection of notes in `org-mode`, each with it's own heading and `org-id`. For example

```
* Note one
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       403847B2-3D4C-4EFB-96DE-E0C5C52A02B5
  :END:

* Note two
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       3F6CD10D-3DE9-4585-8E8F-845F6B5CBA60
  :END:
* Etc.
```

Invariably, I now find that some of these overlap and could be merged or otherwise refiled. The trouble is that many of these notes are linked to from other points in the document, so if I now combine `Note one`and `Note two` under a single `Note one/two` heading, I will more than likely be breaking (at least some of) the links that point to these topics.

Is there a function or workflow for merging headlines that will also update links pointing to them? Or perhaps a way to assign both `org-ids` to the same headline? Something like this, perhaps:

```
* Note one/two
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:      403847B2-3D4C-4EFB-96DE-E0C5C52A02B5; 3F6CD10D-3DE9-4585-8E8F-845F6B5CBA60
  :END:
* Etc.
```

Comment: `org-find-entry-with-id` searches only for exact matches of the id. So there is nothing like alternative ids for the same heading built-in. Furthermore, the ids are hold in a database that assigns files to ids. So it is not very wise to advie `org-find-entry-with-id`. A naive way to replace the id of the removed heading with that one of the combined heading would be `query-replace` for `id:...`. There are many tools for query-replacing in multiple files if that matters for you.

Comment: Perhaps an easier way of handling this situation is to refile "Note two" under "Note one" using the `org-refile` command. This would preserve your links and still keep the contents of both entries together.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias. I'll take a look at query-replace-id.

Comment: Hi @jagrg agreed, it would definitely be easier. But often times I find that writing is an iterative process, where I am constantly organizing and reorganizing and refining my ideas. Unfortunately, as handy as it is to link everything up, it seems that this really handcuffs you creatively, at the same time... unless I am missing something.